# Has SharePoint O365 stopped support of /_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx endpoint recently?

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, office-365

Until now, the legacy **/_vti_bin/UserProfileService.asmx** was the only possible API to update SharePoint o365 user profile properties. Unfortunately, recently it started to return `Server was unable to process request. ---> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.` error message.

I am sure there were no changes to the account name/password/role in o365 from our side. I could not find any announcement or any additional information regarding it.  Does anybody experience the same issue or can confirm the problem?

Comment: I've checked it in my environment, but seems the service is still working. Have you been able to open the URL via browser?

Comment: Yes, the service URL opens in a browser without problem. However, attempt to use any method of the service such as `GetUserProfileCount()` returns the above error. It worked correctly several weeks ago.

Comment: How do you call this web service via code? The most interesting part is how do you get the auth cookies.

Comment: Auth cookies are retrieved the usual way via `SharePointOnlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie()` - no errors here. I think I'll switch to CSOM way of updating user properties. It seems that the new API is available already.

Comment: You get cookies in the right way. How do you assign it to http request?

Answer (score 0):

Nishu, do not substitute SPOIDCRL with FedAuth for your cookie. Instead, use it exactly in a form of SPOIDCRL=...

Alternatively, switch to use PeopleManager via CSOM  https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.userprofiles.peoplemanager.aspx